# Matplotlib cycle color whole figure (not just axes)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I'm writing a style for my matplotlib (v1.5.1) plots and I defined following color cycle:

```
axes.prop_cycle    : cycler('color', ['348ABD', '7A68A6', 'A60628',
                                      '467821', 'CF4457', '188487', 'E24A33'])
```

In some of my plots, however, I have two axes. I would like to have unique colors in my figures, not that the cycle start from the beginning from each axes. Is this possible from the stylesheet?

At present, I simply do this:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
pl1 = ax1.plot(x1, y1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
pl2 = ax2.plot(x2, y2, color=ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler.next()['color'])
pl3 = ax2.plot(x3, y3, color=ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler.next()['color'])
```

Is this the only solution or is there a better solution? It would be great not to have to declare the color everytime.